# Bitmap Hotspots (Image Map)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm building a game where there is a bitmap image (*library symbol*) on the stage, I need to monitor the users mouse gestures over the bitmap.

The idea is that when the user hovers over different points on the image, then different actions will occur (*different actions for different coordinates*).

I have done this in the past, but I cheated by placing invisible MovieClips over the image, and then listened for mouse events on these MovieClips. I can't do it like this now, because there are more than 200 points of interest on the image, having so many extra MovieClips on the stage at on time really slows it all down.

So, I think the best way to do this would be to manually hardcode all the X Y coordinates into the class, then compare with the mouse coords. The problem is that it becomes tricky and my code is bloated and not optimized.

**Is there a common/good way of doing this?**

- All the hotspots are rectangular (*no funny shapes*)
- I want to avoid placing large numbers of MovieClips on the stage
- Using AS3 and CS6 (*not Flex*)
- Willing to use opensource code if there's a recommended project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up the calculation which determines which hotspot (if any) is under the mouse coord you could generate a "hit test" bitmap at startup. This bitmap is never displayed to the user, but each hotspot is drawn as a rectangle with a generated unique color.

For each hotspot you also add an entry to a dictionary (could be a Dictionary instance, an array or normal object) where the key is the color and the value the hotspot. This scales really well, since no matter how many hotspots you have you only need to perform a getPixel() and then check the dictionary for the hotspot.

Comment: I'm very new to Flash and ActionScript. I have a roulette game that I'm coding where this technique sounds perfect for handling chip placement and bet detection on the board. I'm having a tough time visualizing the setup for the hot spot image. Do you know of any example code online?

Comment: the technique I proposed is more applicable if you have many items (in the hundreds or thousands) which you quickly and often need to perform hittest on (say on every mouse move). In a roulette game you should be able to use ActionScripts's .hitTest() without problems.

Comment: I forgot that I posted the comment on this, and I'm not sure if it is perfect, but this seems to be just what I needed. I have a solution coded up already and it seems to work fine. I have 78 target squares with 120 edge rectangles and 39 intersection circles, all with their own actions. I have a MOUSE_MOVE listener that updates the screen to show a "preview" of the bet before they click. Thanks! +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Hardcoding all of the X Y coordinates does seem pretty intense - consider this workaround for placing the rectangles visually:

1. Place the 200 movieclips in the correct locations across the bitmap
2. On starting the game, iterate over the movieclips and add each of their coordinate values to an array of objects with those properties
3. Unload each movieclip as soon as its information is retrieved
4. Listening for mouse events on the *movieclips* in the old scenario can be replaced by listening for corresponding mouse coordinates on *objects* in the new scenario. Instead of checking for whether the mouse rolls over, you can check whether the amount is more than the object's `0,0` and less than its `width,height`.

Is this a feasible solution? It would at least concentrate all of the process-intensive action to the beginning, where it could be loaded, as opposed to spread across the game. Is a bit more intuitive for you as a developer, too.

Comment: To speed up the calculation which determines which hotspot (if any) is under the mouse coord you could generate a "hit test" bitmap at startup. This bitmap is never displayed to the user, but each hotspot is drawn as a rectangle with a generated unique color. For each hotspot you also add an entry to a dictionary (could be Dictionary instance, an array or normal object) where the key is the color and the value the hotspot. This scales _really_ well, since no matter how many hotspots you have you only need to perform a getPixel() and then check the dictionary for the hotspot.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I almost went with it but Strille's comment above got me thinking. It was possible for me to generate the hit test image at compile time.

Comment: @Strille This comment helped me a LOT, it's a technique that I didn't know about before and it's very efficient. I was able to write a JSF Fireworks script to generate the hit test image in advance. If you change your comment to an answer then I will accept.

Comment: No problem at all, and good choice, +1'd Strille's comment for making the approach clever and comprehensive.